# FIDE database used for calculating current ELO

Tags: fide, database, elo

Is there somewhere the database FIDE use for calculating ELO rating of players? No need for PGN of games just game result, date, and players.
Reason: recalculate players rating by using Gliko, with the same games.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there somewhere the database FIDE use for calculating ELO rating of players?

Yes and No.

FIDE have such a database and they let us see some of the data but not in an easily downloadable form. For instance, if I go to my statistics page on the FIDE ratings website I can see a summary of all my results.There is a drop down box on the page which allows me to select an opponent and see my results against that opponent. So, if I select FM Yichen Han I can see on [the page](https://ratings.fide.com/profile/2808617/statistics&opponent=1054430) that I have one draw as white and one win as black. Of course I took the precaution of playing him when he was only half my height and much weaker :-).

The data that FIDE make easily downloadable on [their download page](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) is the rating data but although it includes the number of games each player played in the rating period it does not include results.

> Reason: recalculate players rating by using Gliko, with the same games.

This data is available on the FIDE website but not in an easily downloadable format. You will have to do a lot of screen scraping to get it. To see how let's track down my white win against Yichen Han.

That game was played on 8th January 2017 in the 12th 4NCL Congress Open in England.The [original tournament report](https://ratings.fide.com/view_source.phtml?code=152350) for that tournament is available on the FIDE website. To find it you will need to find the tournament on the [FIDE webpage for Tournaments Received for February 2017 England](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=ENG&rating_period=2017-02-01).

You will find the tournament listed 4 from the bottom. If you click on the blue icon to the left you will get the [Original Tournament Report](https://ratings.fide.com/view_source.phtml?code=152350) listing all the results.

So, what you would need to do is go back to the [Tournaments Received page](https://ratings.fide.com/tournament_list.phtml?moder=ev_code&country=ENG&rating_period=2017-02-01) where you will find at the top a drop down box for all the federations and at the bottom another drop down box for all the periods. You would need to cycle through all the federations and then for each federation cycle through all the periods and then cycle through all the blue-iconed tournaments and extract the results data.